# Losing time value in datetime stamp when import data from Access into R

Tags: r, datetime, ms-access

I am importing data with a DateTime stamp from Access to R and continue to 'lose' my time value.  I have had a similar issue a while back (posted [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172632/converting-excel-datetime-serial-number-to-r-datetime)) and I had to convert the times to a number before importing.  While this was not too difficult, it is a step I would like to avoid.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899516/rodbc-loses-time-values-of-datetime-when-result-set-is-large) is also helpful and suggests the reason might be because of the large number or records.  I am currently trying to import over 110k records.

As an FYI [this post](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html) is very helpful for info on dealing with times in R, but did not provide a specific solution for this issue.

My data in Access (2013) looks like this.
[image]

As you can see I have a UTC and local time, both of which have the date and time in the same field.

I used the following code to read in the table and look at the `head`.

```
DataConnect <- odbcConnect("MstrMUP")
Temp <- sqlFetch(DataConnect, "TempData_3Nov2014")
head(Temp)

      IndID UTCDateTime LocalDateTime Temp
1 MTG_030_A  2013-02-08    2013-02-08   25
2 MTG_030_A  2013-02-08    2013-02-08   26
3 MTG_030_A  2013-02-08    2013-02-08   31
4 MTG_030_A  2013-02-08    2013-02-08   29
5 MTG_030_A  2013-02-09    2013-02-08   39
6 MTG_030_A  2013-02-09    2013-02-08   44
```

As you can see, the time portion of the DateTime stamp is missing, and I can not seem to locate it using `str` or `as.numeric`, both of which suggest the time value is not stored (at least that is how I read it).

```
> str(Temp)
'data.frame':   110382 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ IndID        : Factor w/ 17 levels "BHS_034_A","BHS_035_A",..: 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 ...
 $ UTCDateTime  : POSIXct, format: "2013-02-08" "2013-02-08" ...
 $ LocalDateTime: POSIXct, format: "2013-02-08" "2013-02-08" ...
 $ Temp         : int  25 26 31 29 39 44 42 49 42 38 ...

> head(as.numeric(MTG30$LocalDateTime))
[1] 1360306800 1360306800 1360306800 1360306800 1360306800 1360306800
```

Because all numeric values are the same, they must all be the same date, and do not include time.  Correct...?

The Question:
Is this an R issue or Access?  Any suggestions on how to import 110k rows of data from Access into R without losing the time portion of a DateTime stamp would be appreciated.

I am sure there is a better method than my [earlier work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172632/converting-excel-datetime-serial-number-to-r-datetime)

oh, I almost forgot, I am running the "Sock it to Me" version of R.

**EDIT/ADDITION** In response to @Richard Scriven thoughts on `unclass`
Unfortunatly, no, there is not a sec, min, or time value.  All are 0.

```
> temp <- Temp[1:5,]
> unclass(as.POSIXlt(temp$UTCDateTime))
$sec
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
$min
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
$hour
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
$mday
[1] 8 8 8 8 9
$mon
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
$year
[1] 113 113 113 113 113
$wday
[1] 5 5 5 5 6
$yday
[1] 38 38 38 38 39
$isdst
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
$zone
[1] "MST" "MST" "MST" "MST" "MST"
$gmtoff
[1] -25200 -25200 -25200 -25200 -25200
attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""    "MST" "MDT"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at `unclass(as.POSIXlt(Temp$UTCDateTime))`.  It should produce a list of attributes for the timestamp, and hopefully there are values for the hours, mins, seconds